# How to enable pre-registration feature for app in GooglePlay

Tags: android, google-play

There is an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glu.t5&hl=en) in GooglePlay with pre-registration feature. I found a lot of [announcements](http://www.mobyaffiliates.com/blog/google-adds-app-pre-registration-feature-to-google-play-store/) with this news, but I can't find instructions how to do this. 
Does anyone know to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any info on websites about how to active it, and I've scoured my developer console, both on published and unpublished apps, looking for some magic "pre-register" button. Can't find anything.

My feeling is that this is a tool/feature that is pretty much unique to [The New Terminator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.glu.t5) (at least for now). I'd imagine if it were open to everyone, there's the possibility that the Play store could fill up with hundreds of apps that haven't actually been released yet, and may end up never being so. This wouldn't be great for the store, making it hard to actually find downloadable apps.

So we'll see, but I doubt this will be an option open to every developer out there.

Answer (score 0):

> To make your app or game available for pre-registration, you select
>   the countries where you want users to be able to pre-register. Here’s
>   how:
>
> 1. Sign in to your Play Console.
> 2. Select an app or game
> 3. On the left menu, click Release management > App releases.
> 4. In the “Pre-registration” section, click Manage.
> 5. In the “Manage pre-registration countries” section, select Pre-registration next to the countries where you want to use
>      pre-registration.
> 6. Click Save.

Instructions found at
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9084187?hl=en